# Non-Blocking Queue with batch oriented drainAll

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, nonblocking

We have a specialist,  multi-producer (User) and single-consumer (Engine), queue. The User threads runs more frequently and always adds individual elements to the queue. The Engine thread operation runs less frequently and processes the stack elements in a batch. If the stack is empty, it'll park until the User thread has added an entry. This way a notify only needs to happen when the queue goes from empty to 1.

In this implementation, instead of the Engine thread iterating and removing one item at a time, it removes them all - a drainAll, instead of drainTo. No other operations can mutate the stack - just the User thread add, and the engine thread drainAll.

Currently we do this via a synchronised linked list, we are wondering if there is a non-blocking way to do this. The drainTo operation on JDK classes will iterate the stack, we just want to take everything in the stack in one operation, without iterating - as each iteration hits volatile/cas related logic, so we'd ideally just like to hit that once, per drainAll. The the engine thread can iterate and operate on each individual element, without touching sync/volatile/cas operations.

The current implementation looks something like:

```
public class SynchronizedPropagationQueue implements PropagatioQueue {
    protected volatile PropagationEntry head;
    protected volatile PropagationEntry tail;

    protected synchronized void addEntry( PropagationEntry entry ) {
        if ( head == null ) {
            head = entry;
            notifyWaitOnRest();
        } else {
            tail.setNext( entry );
        }
        tail = entry;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized PropagationEntry drainAll() {
        PropagationEntry currentHead = head;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        return currentHead;
    }

    public synchronized void waitOnRest() {
        try {
            log.debug("Engine wait");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        log.debug("Engine resumed");
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void notifyWaitOnRest() {
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

asdf

Comment: Is your implementation somehow better than `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` for example?

Comment: If the engine wakes up every time the size of the queue changes from zero to one, then why do you expect it to perform any differently from an engine that simply waits on a `BlockingQueue`, and performs each task as it arrives?

Comment: Where is your "synchronised linked list" in your code?

Comment: and what would you like to be non-blocking drainAll only or all the methods of SynchronizedPropagationQueue?

Comment: "Is your implementation somehow better than ConcurrentLinkedDeque for example?". ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not have a drainAll.

Comment: All the methods are synchronised and the field volatile, it was a first "good enough" approach, and we found it performed better than ConcurrentLinkedQueue/BlockingQueue, in our application; which initially is a two threaded environment (separate U and separate E thread). ConcurrentLinkedQueue/BlockingQueue does not have a drainAll, and this seemed to be the main difference. Now that we are upping the number of threads, looking to go for something a bitter smarter - a non-blocking implementation that supports drainAll().

Comment: FYI: You don't have to have `volatile` fields if everything is protected with `synchronized`.

Comment: @MarkProctor do you still need a wait/notify mechanism in the new expected non blocking implementation?

Comment: "@MarkProctor do you still need a wait/notify mechanism in the new expected non blocking implementation?" When there is no work, the Engine thread does indeed need to park.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks have a very simple non-blocking implementation that supports a concurrent "pop all" operation easily, and can easily detect the empty->non-empty transition.  You could have all your producers push items onto a stack and then have the engine empty the whole thing at once.  It looks like this:

```
public class EngineQueue<T>
{
    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> m_lastItem = new AtomicReference<>();

    public void add(T item)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(item);
        do {
            newNode.m_next = m_lastItem.get();
        } while(!m_lastItem.compareAndSet(newNode.m_next, newNode)); 

        if (newNode.m_next == null)
        {
            // ... just went non-empty signal any waiting consumer
        }
    }

    public List<T> removeAll()
    {
        Node<T> stack = m_lastItem.getAndSet(null);
        // ... wait for non-empty if necessary 
        List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (;stack != null; stack=stack.m_next)
        {
            ret.add(stack.m_data);
        }
        Collections.reverse(ret);
        return ret;
    }
    private static class Node<U>
    {
        Node<U> m_next;
        final U m_data;
        Node(U data)
        {
            super();
            m_data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

For signaling around the empty -> non-empty transition, you can use normal synchronization.  This is not going to be expensive if you only do it when you detect an empty state... since you only get to the empty state when you're out of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently we do this via a synchronised linked list, we are wondering if there is a non-blocking way to do this. The drainTo operation on JDK classes will iterate the stack, we just want to take everything in the stack in one operation, without iterating

Maybe I don't understand but it seems like using a `BlockingQueue.drainTo(...)` method would be better than your implementation.  For example the `LinkedBlockingQueue.drainTo(...)` method just has one lock around that method -- there's no iterating overhead that I see.

If this is not an academic discussion then I'd doubt that your performance problems are with the queue itself and would concentrate your efforts in other areas.  If it is academic then @Matt's answer might be better although certainly there's a lot more code to be written to support the full `Collection` method list.

Comment: drainTo still applies a lock, so its's no better off, and additional it requires a full iteration and then collection population. Where as we just return the head and use that directly. Our first implementation used a JDK queue, and the above implementation performed better, but it was not under stress from multiple threads.

Comment: This smacks of premature optimization to me @MarkProctor.  Unless a profiler has indicated that this code is the source of your problem I'd concentrate your work elsewhere.